# UIButton click not working if it is integrated in SwiftUI project

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uibutton, uikit

In SwiftUI I have a VStack with tap gesture enabled. And this VStack Contains two buttons. One button is from UIKit and other one is from SwiftUI itself.
If I click SwiftUI button, it is working as expected. But when I click UIKit button it is not working instead tap gesture is triggering, reason the tap gesture is enabled for VStack.

How to make UIKit button action works, if the tap gesture is enabled?
I have to support my project from iOS 14 and tap gesture should be enabled for VStack.

SwiftUI Code

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Bridge()
                    .frame(height: 100)
                Button("SwiftUI Button") {
                    debugPrint("SwiftUI Button Clicked")
                }
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                debugPrint("User tapped")
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
```

Bridge Code

```
struct Bridge: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        return UIKitButtonView()
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) { }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject {}
}
```

UIView Code

```
class UIKitButtonView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var uikitButton: UIButton!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    private func setup() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("UIKitButtonView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
    }
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        debugPrint("UIKit button clicked")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Quick searching, I haven't seen a good workaround. The tap gesture is "eating" the touch-up event. Notice that if you long-press on the UIKit button, you'll bypass the tap and the `@IBAction` **will** be triggered. One possibility is to assign a tap gesture to the UIKit button instead of `.touchUpInside` ... you'll still get the VStack tap, but you'll also get the button tap... you'd need to find a way to recognize the sequence.

Comment: @DonMag thanks for your comment. Long press I have tried it is working but that is not the expectation. I tried to add tap gesture to UIButton in my sample project and tapping is happening in both VStack and UIButton. Thanks. In real project UIButton is from third party framework I don't have any control to add tap gesture to button. In VStack tap gesture closure I'm dismissing the keyboard. `UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from:nil, for:nil)`. Is there anyway to achieve this functionality without tap gesture to VStack?

Comment: Sorry, but I have done very little with SwiftUI ... you might want to search for `swiftui pass through gesture` ?

Comment: @Sai I have the same problem, Have you solved it already?

Comment: @pfcstyle No. Only possibility is to add tap gesture to UIKit button.